# Failed to resolved: compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.passitonkentucky.fayetteresources"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
     compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

I downloaded Android 3.0.1, before this I had error minimum version 3.0.
When that's resolved, it's now showing me error.
(27,4).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First you should avoid using "+" in version number its bad practice. add version number will solve your problem.

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
```